# Ionic splash screen stuck

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ibeacon

I'm working on a Ionic 1 project. All was working good but since a couple of days the splash screen will not disappear on iOS whilst it does on Android. 
Can't find help on Google. Anyone here any ideas? Console from

xCode:

```js
2017-02-27 16:05:18.509136 MyApp[675:146852] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.3.1 is starting.

2017-02-27 16:05:18.510432 MyApp[675:146852] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES

2017-02-27 16:05:18.620831 MyApp[675:146852] Using UIWebView

2017-02-27 16:05:18.624093 MyApp[675:146852] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.158012ms

2017-02-27 16:05:18.626880 MyApp[675:146852] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 2.615988ms

2017-02-27 16:05:18.627228 MyApp[675:146852] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.162005ms

2017-02-27 16:05:18.663198 MyApp[675:146852] [CDVTimer][file] 35.710990ms

2017-02-27 16:05:18.685646 MyApp[675:146852] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 22.248030ms

2017-02-27 16:05:18.697926 MyApp[675:146852] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 12.024999ms

2017-02-27 16:05:18.701478 MyApp[675:146852] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 3.291011ms

2017-02-27 16:05:18.701717 MyApp[675:146852] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 77.835977ms

2017-02-27 16:05:19.129788 MyApp[675:146852] Resetting plugins due to page load.

2017-02-27 16:05:20.621608 MyApp[675:146852] *** Assertion failure in -[CLLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreLocationFramework/CoreLocation-2100.0.34/Framework/CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.m:649

2017-02-27 16:05:20.623636 MyApp[675:146852] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInternalInconsistencyException> Invalid parameter not satisfying: !stayUp || CLClientIsBackgroundable(internal->fClient)

2017-02-27 16:05:20.642503 MyApp[675:146852] didChangeAuthorizationStatus

2017-02-27 16:05:20.642915 MyApp[675:146852] Invalid callback id received by sendPluginResult

2017-02-27 16:05:50.663236 MyApp[675:146852] deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.

2017-02-27 16:05:50.663683 MyApp[675:146852] Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady

2017-02-27 16:05:50.663962 MyApp[675:146852] Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady

2017-02-27 16:05:50.664506 MyApp[675:146852] Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady

2017-02-27 16:05:50.664951 MyApp[675:146852] ERROR: [Cordova-Plugin-IBeacon] WARNING did not receive delegate ready callback from DOM after 30.000000 seconds!
```

So many errors following each other!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that I had cordova.js not as the last inclusion in index.html. Causing the JS binds to fail this failing to call the ready function upon which I hide the splashscreen